# Empty AdMob banner, test Ad ID works, not the live one

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Quick and to the point:

My Android Studio project doesn't show AdMob banners with the real Ad unit ID. But when I use Test Ad ID, it shows up!! Where's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: can u show ur code?have u mention in Manifest file?

Comment: I would, but I also tested on the template sample of Android Studio as well. The test Ad id works, but mine doesn't. Same thing vice versa. My app can show test banner, but not the live ones. very frustrating.

Comment: Read this and at the end download sample , hope so u will get it or post your code step by step for admob which u did.https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Are Ad IDs on AdMob app specific? or they can be used on another app?

Comment: You can not use one admob ID to an other app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, but I was testing right after creating a new Ad unit ID. After a couple of hours the real banner showed up on my App.